# How can I combine MinimumSize with AutoScrollMinSize in c# .net dockable forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autoscroll

I want my dockable Winforms to have a minimum size when floating. They also show scrollbars if they are minimized to less than a set AutoScrollMinSize property. If I add a MinimumSize property to get a desired behaviour the scrollbars stop working.

How can I both use the AutoScrollMinSize and the MinimumSize properties on my forms? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoScrollMinSize to some value smaller than MinimumSize so the form will still display scroll bars even if the form is at its minimum size.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If the MinimumSize is set to the same or more than AutoScrollMinSize the scrolls don't appear. Is there another property one has to set in order for this to work?

Comment: Then your only option is to manually add ScrollBar components to your form and handle scrolling manually. This is a bit complex so its your call.